# How can I get the date after one week in iOS programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, dayofweek

I am very new to iOS development. I want to get the date after one week.

I use the code to get the current date as below.

```
NSDate *currentDateTime = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE,MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *dateInStringFormated = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDateTime];

NSLog(@"%@", dateInStringFormated);
```

If I have the current date as 12/03/2013 I want to get the date after one week means get the 19/03/2013.

Comment: possible duplicate [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8165201/1031955)

Answer (score 13):

Use [`NSDateComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
comps.day = 7;
NSDate *sevenDays = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
```

Comment: Technically, though, it looks like OP wants "7 days" and not "1 week" (title and content are conflicting).  I believe 1 week is more than 7 days in some calendars.  That's pedantic though.

Comment: use Plus "+" for after days and minus "-"for before days

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setDay:+7];
NSDate *afterSevenDays = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:todayDate options:0];
NSLog(@"todayDate: %@", todayDate);
NSLog(@"afterSevenDays: %@", afterSevenDays);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  NSCalendar *calendar=[NSCalendar currentCalendar];    
  NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
components.day = 7;
NSDate *fireDate =[calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
```